# Converting an enum string javascript to enum in C# when there is a space

Tags: c#, angular, enums

I currently have enums in the front end:

```
export enum ContactType {
  Vendor = 'Vendor',
  Buyer  = 'Buyer',
  Feedlot = 'Feed Lot',
  ...
}
```

An enum in the backend:

```
public enum ContactType 
{
   Vendor,
   Buyer,
   Feedlot,
   ...
}
```

And I have a converter to turn a string into an enum:

```
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter()));
```

The string to enum conversion works fine except for `Feed Lot` due to the spacing. Is there a way I can remove the spacing before I send the request or remove it when I read it on the backend?

Comment: You can use  `[EnumMember(Value = "Feed Lot")] FeedLot` or do you consider only removing space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EnumMember` attribute in the backend to specify the actual string value of each enum member.

```
public enum ContactType 
{
    Vendor,
    Buyer,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Feed Lot")]
    FeedLot,
    ...
}
```